# What is possible in SOQL but not in SQL?

Tags: sql, salesforce, apex, soql

Are there any functions / keywords / syntax in SOQL queries that does NOT have an equivalent operation in SQL?

Basically, does there exist a SOQL query that you couldn't convert directly into a SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird question, why do you ask? And which SQL you mean exactly, Oracle, SQL Server flavour, Maria DB or what?

I'd say you'll have hard time

- mapping `SELECT Account.Owner.Manager.Profile.Name FROM Opportunity` into "normal" joins
- replicating TOLABEL() (translate picklist values on the fly)
- replicating anything SF-specific like [WITH](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with_datacategory.htm) (say knowledge base's data categories) or [USING SCOPE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_using_scope.htm) (you can pull "my accounts" but can you pull "my team's accounts"? "My territory's accounts"? Without an orgy of joins)
- doing joins over <strike>mutant</strike> polymorphic fields like `Task.WhatId` or `ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId`
- doing any kind of SOSL, especially if org uses synonyms
- converting currencies on the fly
- doing things like FISCAL_YEAR() without orgy of joins to Period table
- replicating any [geolocation-related queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm) (accounts up to 10 km away from me) without knowing exactly what GIS (or whatever) SF uses
- doing soft deletes (or however Recycle Bin really works) without impact on performance. I mean if records go to another table - columns are identical and join/view happens magically when you query ALL ROWS?
- doing any Person Account stuff, silently querying and updating effectively 2 tables (as materialised view maybe?)

Comment: I am talking about sql server.  Thanks a bunch this is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Some differences of SOQL:

No SELECT *

No views

SOQL read-only

Limited indexes

Object-relational mapping is automatic

Schema changes protected

Comment: Thanks but these all seem like SOQL limitations.  Seeking SQL limitations related to SOQL